# How to get my theme settings back after update?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, themes, settings

I did a dist-upgrade yesterday and it appears to have broken my gtk theme (and touch pad scrolling + tap and font preferences!).

e.g. firefox prefs dialog:
[image: screenshot showing ugly old widgets]

I know it's my settings because if I create a new user, everything is OK. But I don't want to recreate my user account just to get the Desktop to behave. Changing the theme settings in "Advanced Settings" (tweak) now has no effect.

How can I reset the gnome/desktop config?

I'm using Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 1):

Log out.

Log in as different user (or as I did, on a virtual terminal).

```
mv ~/{.config/,}gnome-control-center
```

That will move the gnome-control-center dir into your home dir - just as a backup.

Then log in and use tweak tool to re-set your settings.

Comment: It was a Cinnamon package that was causing the probs, by the way, just in case anyone has dabbled with that like I had!